# Make a script run at startup

Tags: 12.04, startup, brightness, backlight

First of all,sorry for my bad English.

- Im using Xubuntu 12.04 on Acer Aspire One D270.My Screen brightness
  hotkeys (Fn+L/R) dont work.I installed xbacklight but it always shows
  "No outputs have backlight property". So I used this command: `sudo
  setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80` and it does work!
- I made a session startup name "Brightness",Command:"sudo setpci -s
  00:02.0 F4.B=80" but still have to manually execute from Terminal.

Both with xbacklight or Startup Script is OK,as long as I can control my screen brightness.

P/S:Im noob,so please explain in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Now that `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80` is working for you, lets make it executed everytime you login.

Please do the following

1. `sudo vim /etc/rc.local`

   It might ask you to enter your root password. and then it will open
   up a window
2. Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. This will take you to the
   last line of the file.
3. Press <kbd>i</kbd>
4. Now type `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80`
5. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
6. And then type <kbd>:wq</kbd>

Thats it. Restart your computer. That command will be executed automatically everytime you login, so that you dont have to execute it manually.

Comment: Can you please format your texT? Please use this for help in formatting http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: thank you,sir.I installed vim and did exactly what you said.It looks like:  echo 6 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness  sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80  exit 0   
then type :wq,press Enter.  Still have to execute manually :(

Comment: So, you have saved that file with `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80` in it, right?

Comment: yes,right between "echo 6> blah blah" and  "exit 0"

Comment: Fine, now restart and see whether it is working properly.

Comment: I did sudo reboot and the problem is still there T.T

Comment: Can you please take a screen print of your /etc/rc.local file, upload it to a free image hosting service and share the link here?

Comment: Here it is. http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h129/nirtn/Screenshot-04272013-044810PM_zps878a2a6b.png

Comment: Try `source /etc/rc.local` from a terminal. This should not show any error